# Error setting Calender.DAY_OF_WEEK

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, parse-platform

I am working with Parse, in which I am storing user ratings of products.  On the user dashboard I am displaying how many ratings the user has completed this week, this month and in total.

To get home many this week I am using the following code:

```
public getWeeklyRatingsTask(final String userId, final RemoteCallListener callListener){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,1);

    Log.i("USER ID ===============++++++", userId);

    Date date = calendar.getTime();

    Log.i("DATE----====----====--", String.valueOf(date));
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("beer_rating");
    query.whereEqualTo("userId", userId);
    query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", date);
    query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(int beerCount, ParseException e) {

            if(e==null) {
                callListener.onRemoteCallComplete(beerCount);
                Log.i("WEEKLY BEER COUNT TASK  ================", String.valueOf(beerCount));
            }
            else{
                callListener.onRemoteErrorOccur(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

So I am testing this on three devices, xxhdpi (running 4.4.2), xhdpi (4.3), and hdpi (4.1.2).

On the xxhdpi and xhdpi this get's the weekly count correctly.  However, on the hdpi device (samsung s3 mini) it returns zero.

So where I log  `Log.i("DATE----====----====--", String.valueOf(date));` on the xxhdpi and xhdpi it logs `Sun Aug 03 11:50:04 GMT+01:00 2014` however with the hdpi is logs `Sun Aug 10 11:50:04 GMT+01:00 2014`.

If anyone can help me out on this I'd greatly appreciate it...I'm sure I can just add a check if it's a versioning issue and apply different methodology.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I could solve it with a call to `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` before I wanted to get the `Date`.

Comment: @PsHegger Reading the source it shouldn't make a difference though. http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Calendar.java#1020

Comment: @DJ-DOO Are you running on different locales, such as one with first day of week as sunday and the other as monday?

Comment: @laalto I know, and that's why I don't understand why this happens

Comment: @laalto I'm not sure I follow? This is the only code I use to fetch the day of week and as per http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY I've set it to 1...I don't really understand it

Comment: Date calculation depends on locale-specific "first day of week" setting. For some locales, sunday is the first day, for some, it's the last.

Comment: but even if that were the cause of the issue should this not then be the same with the other two devices?

Comment: I don't know what's the locale setting on those devices. Instead of hardcoding `SUNDAY`, consider setting the caledar day of week to what is returned by `getFirstDayOfWeek()`.

Comment: that did the trick!! can you set that as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Day of week calculation depends on the locale-specific first day of week setting.

In some locales, Sunday is the first day of the week. In some other locales, Sunday is the last day of the week. Setting the day-of-week setting to Sunday sets the calendar to Sunday on the current week which can set the calendar backwards or forwards in time, depending on locale.

Instead of hardcoding Sunday as the first day of week, use [`getFirstDayOfWeek()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()) to get the locale-specific first day of current week.